# ingress contour add basic http authentication

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, contour

I use `countor` as ingress nginx class for my ingress and try to add basic http authentication but it doesn't work.I wonder why it doesn't work?

What i'm missed?

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-prod
    ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: contour
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
    
    # It doesn't work
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-type: basic
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-secret: basic-auth
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-realm: 'Authentication Required - foo'


spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - my_domen.com
      secretName: mysecretname
  rules:
    - host: my_domen.com
      http:
        paths:
          - pathType: Prefix
            path: /
            backend:
              service:
                name: some-service
                port:
                  number:
                    8083
```

Answer (score 0):

Contour is not nginx based so the nginx annotations don't have an effect. As far as I'm aware, you need to run this process: https://projectcontour.io/guides/external-authorization/